# Correct way to pass options to (class) loaded packages

Tags: conditionals, document-classes, tufte, package-options

I write a document with the `book` class and have a file (`mainstyle.sty`) with a number of packages that I use (`pdfx`, `lipsum`, `placeins`, etc`\ldots`).

I recently started playing around with `tufte-book` and got several warnings, errors and unpleasant messages. Got my hands on it, but I realise that it will take time to tune it little by little. I would like to switch classes easily and load the corresponding packages and options easily.

The main issue here is that the class `tufte-book` loads several packages previously, and thus my file crashes if I just change the class on the fly.

Right now, what I have in *master.tex* is:

```
%\documentclass[a4paper]{tuftebook}
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{./inc/mainstyle}

\begin{document}
    text text text
\end{document}
```

My idea now is to split `mainstyle.sty` in two files and use a mixture of conditionals and `\PassOptionsToPackage` (inspired by [these](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25370/) two [questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67782/)). The idea would be to have a `parameters.sty` file and a `load.sty` file, with the main document modified like:

```
\input{./inc/parameters}
%\documentclass[a4paper]{tuftebook}
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\input{./inc/load}

\begin{document}
    text text text
\end{document}
```

Then I'd have something like:

```
%parameters.tex ---------
\PassOptionsToPackage{pdftex,pdfa,hidelinks}
```

and:

```
%% load.tex ------------
\makeatletter

\@ifclassloaded{book}{
    \usepackage{hyperref}
}{
    \@ifclassloaded{tufte-book}{
        % hyperref was already loaded
    }
}

\makeatother
```

This is roughly the same that is proposed in this [other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124049/), right?

However, it feels cumbersome and I don't know if I'm just messing things around. Also, my understanding of conditionals/macros and such is still very limited.

Is this the right way to go?

Comment: Stopped reading in the middle. There is no real use to switch classes easily. Decide now and do it properly instead of wasting time (procrastinate) in doing conditionals.

Comment: Tufte has the option `nohyper` which is a splendig idea. It should be used by everyone as `hyperref` should **NEVER** be loaded by a freaking class file. It cuts off *YOUR* control.

Comment: @Johannes_B [Hehe, you made me remember this comic :)](https://www.xkcd.com/1445/)(took me less than 2 hours to find it again)
Thanks for the `nohyper` tip, I have it in my code already.

Comment: @Johannes_B Easy to say, but when the class is modifying the same macros that hyperref modifies, you have an arms race. There are some workarounds (like using the [`filehook` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/filehook) to patch/repatch macros after a package has been loaded, but that's just kicking the can farther down the road in some cases.

Comment: Do you really need extra conditions? Can't you instead just use `\@ifclassloaded` and `\@ifpackageloaded`?

Comment: @godbyk `hyperref` redefines *a lot* of macros, also from packages. Hence the rule of thumb: Load hyperref as late as possible in the preamble. But there are exceptions.

Comment: @Andrew Which extra conditions do you mean? I have only `\@ifclassloaded` right now. The idea to put two in a sort of `if-then-else-default`-construction was to avoid other classes, and may be deleted, yes.

Comment: @Luis Sorry, I misunderstood!. I thought that you were adding new conditionals for several packages...

Comment: @Andrew No problem, and thanks for having a look! :)